# chat sound is not coming in android device

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, audio

i am trying for chat sound to come in android but it is not working however same code is workign fine in pc.

when i open in mobile browser the chat notification sound will not come however same will come  when we use pc

```
  $jn(window).load(function() {
        $jn(document).ready(function() {

            //$jn('#chatboxhead'+id).css('background-image','url('+FreiChat.make_url(freidefines.newtopimg)+')');
            soundManager.onready(function()
            {
                if (soundManager.supported() && Get_Cookie('frei_sound') === "on")
                {
                    try {
                        mobile.sound = soundManager.createSound({
                            id: 'mobile_beep',
                            url: freidefines.GEN.url + "client/jquery/img/newmsg.mp3"
                        });
                        mobile.can_play_sound = true;

                    } catch (e) {
                        FreiChat.buglog("info", "SoundManager Error: " + e);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    FreiChat.buglog("info", "SoundManager does not support your system");
                }
            });
```

Comment: where is your `.play()` method?

Comment: @jai here is chat and all supporting function  http://way2enjoy.com/

Comment: oops! not opening some web filter is blocking in our network.